# How to set up a new Wi-Fi access point in C++ Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5, objective-c++

I am developing a C++\Qt application for windows and Mac. Qt doesn’t have a support for configuration of any new Access Point. However it will connect to the configured access points( i.e. which are known to the machine). So need to use Native API to configure new accesspoints (i.e user has not created a profile for the accesspoint).

WlanSetProfile() will do this on windows. similarly i want to know for Mac OS.

Thank you.
Pratap

Answer (score 0):

OS X has the `CoreWLANWirelessManager` API, however it's in Objective-C so it's not going to be particularly straightforward to integrate it: [CoreWLANWirelessManager docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008921-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Comment: You mean there is no C/C++ API?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no, because with OS X Apple only really builds out for Objective-C so all their API's are built around it.